# Kubernetes: Image garbage collection failed: unable to find data for container /

Tags: kubernetes, container-image

I have problem with containers `garbage collection`.

When I start `kubelet` I have an error:

```
E1006 08:04:08.856100   25155 kubelet.go:682] Image garbage collection failed: unable to find data for container /
```

And `garbage collection` doesn't work.

`kubernetes v1.0.6`


How to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

The error message is from cadvisor, which gathers container stats. You can try `curl http://127.0.0.1:4194/validate/` on your node and to see if there is any problem preventing cadvisor from functioning correctly.

Unlike image garbage collection (GC), container GC does not rely on cadvisor. You may want to check your [GC policy settings](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/80f2d89a79bee987e6c1553ff7617a7c71b977d9/docs/admin/garbage-collection.md) to see if the parameters are set correctly.