# Image garbage collection failed: unable to find data for container /

Tags: kubernetes, kubelet

I know this question has been asked ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32977617/kubernetes-image-garbage-collection-failed-unable-to-find-data-for-container)), but it's not help for me. I will describe my problem in details.

I installed my kubernetes cluster on `CentOS 7 vm` os, etcd and kubernetes versions are:

```
kubernetes v1.6.6
etcd       v3.1.9
```

When I start kubelet, I got these errors:

> E0620 09:57:38.178381   30625 kubelet.go:1165] Image garbage
>   collection failed: unable to find data for container / E0620
>   09:57:38.203274   30625 factory.go:305] devicemapper filesystem stats
>   will not be reported: usage of thin_ls is disabled to preserve iops

On the kube-master vm, I check the node states and got these results:

```
$ kubectl get nodes
NAME        STATUS    AGE       VERSION
k8s-node1   Ready     1h        v1.6.6
k8s-node2   Ready     1h        v1.6.6
```

But When check the nodes in details, I got warnings:

```
$ kubectl describe nodes k8s-node1
...
Events:
FirstSeen  LastSeen  Count  From  SubObjectPath  Type  Reason  Message
39m     39m     1   kubelet, k8s-node1 Warning      ImageGCFailed       unable to find data for container /
```

I've googled the question, but can't figure it out. How can I fix it?

Comment: how did you install the cluster? did  you use the kubeadm to install the cluster? with this step: https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/create-cluster-kubeadm/

Comment: Can you run this script https://github.com/moby/moby/blob/master/contrib/check-config.sh and check if all the requirements for docker are fullfilled?

Comment: I install my kubernetes cluster from binary. I just copy the binary file and write some `systemd service` file to boot kubernetes service. Not all the requirements for docker are fullfilled. Since the the results is too long, I just copy the items not satisfied, as follows:

Comment: (RHEL7/CentOS7: User namespaces disabled; add 'user_namespace.enable=1' to boot command line)

Comment: - CONFIG_RESOURCE_COUNTERS: missing

Comment: - "ipvlan":
    - CONFIG_IPVLAN: missing

Comment: - Storage Drivers:
  - "aufs":
    - CONFIG_AUFS_FS: missing
  - "zfs":
    - /dev/zfs: missing
    - zfs command: missing
    - zpool command: missing

Comment: Did you find out how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

add configer “--allow-privileged=true“ to kubelet configfile